# What is wrong on the setting of the attributed typing text of this UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

The log of this code prints (null) and I have no idea why this is.

```
NSDictionary *dict = self.textField.typingAttributes;
NSMutableDictionary *mutaDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
mutaDict[NSKernAttributeName] = @(2.0f);
self.textField.typingAttributes = mutaDict;
NSLog(@"%@", self.textField.typingAttributes);
```

I have tried adding other attributes that are not the kern, different ways of creating the dictionary, and I have also tried attributedText (which works but it doesn't show the place holder, and if I set the initial string to @"", the attributed effect does not occur).

Any new ideas or way to solve this code?

I deeply appreciated, thank you :-)

Comment: If the text field is not in editing mode, this property contains the value nil. Similarly, you cannot assign a value to this property unless the text field is currently in editing mode.

Comment: Do you really have a property named `UITextField`? That's a bad practice. 1) variable and method names should begin with lowercase, 2) Don't ever name a property, variable, or method the same as the name of a class. That's too confusing.

Comment: rmaddy I changed it for the purpose of simplicity, it has another name obviously

Comment: @user3726682 Please change it back. It actually makes reading and understanding the code harder because all I see is an out-of-place class name in the code. And FYI - when you replay to someone, precede their username with an "@" sign so they get notified of the comment.